# How to get data in params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Car model and an Brand model (each of which has_and_belongs_to_many). I am trying to create a new brand for a car. The car model accepts nested attributes for brand.

When I try

```
@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
@brand = @car.brands.build(params[:brand])
```

I get a mass assignment error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: brands
```

Brands Controller:

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  debugger
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  @brand= @car.brands.build(params[:brand])
  if @brand.save
   redirect_to @car
  else
   #do something
  end
 end 
end
```

Calling the debugger with

```
pp params
```

Shows:

```
"brand"=>{"brands"=>{"name"=>"BMW"}},
"commit"=>"Create Brand",
"action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"brands",
"car_id"=>"4"}
```

The view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@car, @car.brands.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.fields_for :brands do |a| %>
            <%= a.text_field :name, placeholder: "New Brand" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

I want the application to be secure so I want to set the brand attributes individually as opposed to passing the whole "brand" hash (which incidentally does not work). How can I get the brand name? Something like

```
params[:brands].name?
```

**Edit:**

I can get the brand name with 'params[:brand][:brands][:name]'. Now it turns out that the brands table does not have a car_id since it is connected to a car with a join table.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :brands do |a| %>
        <%= a.text_field :name, placeholder: "New Brand" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

In your model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brands
  attr_accessible :brand_attributes
end
```

Comment: after your change I still get the 'Can't mass-assign protected attributes: brands' error

Comment: Car needs to have an attr_accessible :brand_attributes as that form helper should output params[:car][:brand_attributes] which will either be a hash or an array for one or more brands being submitted. Also the controller shouldn't be using brands.build since thats what ANAF does. The controller should be just the normal create/update_attrbitues

Answer (score 1):

Although having a model accept attributes for another is a useful tool in some cases, it often tends to be cumbersome and violates single responsibility principal not only at the model level, but also at the controller and view layer. Ultimately making it more difficult to refactor should your design need to change.

Keeping with the philosophy of REST, instead of creating Brands through Cars, use a BrandsController to handle the lifecycle of a Brand.

As for your requirement of security, setting a model's attributes manually does not provide any more security then passing the whole params hash assuming you are properly using attr_accessible. Giving it a whitelist of acceptable paramaters will tell the AR interface that everything else should be denied.

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

So if a brand belongs to a car, and someone tried to change the relationship by hacking a car_id into the form it would reject car_id from the hash, possibly even raising an exception depending on your settings.

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

That will cause a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` instead of just the Warning that is output into the logs.

Comment: I have a brands controller. I have updated the question to show it.

Comment: If you have that, then why bother with the nested form for? It looks like you have a nested resource already, which is all you really need to ensure the link between the created Brand and the Car, i would drop the form/model nesting and just use form_for(@brand) and be done with it.